# List Video Filename and Duration for multiple files in folder and subfolders with path too if possible

Tags: command-line, video

I need to get a list of filenames and path along with the duration of the file. All are video files. Some files are in subfolders as well. I need the list sorted according to duration.
My goal is to delete the files which have a duration lower than 2 minutes.
Is there someway I can do it through terminal or GUI?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/681388/295286

Answer (score 2):

this should give you a list of mp4s less than 120 seconds in the folder specified including sub folders

```
find ~/pathtofolder -iname '*.mp4' -type f > vidfiles && while read f; do echo -n "$f: "; ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$f"; done < vidfiles | awk '$NF<120' > shortvids
```

Just change the `~/pathtofolder` to your target location.

The list will be in a file called `shortvids`

I apologize for not sorting but I don't see the need if the only files in the list are the short videos.

If you would like to change the duration, near the end change `'$NF<120'` to the number of seconds.  For example `'$NF<300'` would mean "**duration less than 5 minutes(or 300 seconds)**"

of course you can also find durations **greater than** or **equal to** by changing the sign ie. `<` to `>` or `=`

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck without using external programmes, `file videoname.xyz` does not return the duration of the videos. On the other hand, **avprobe (ffprobe)** from the package **libav-tools** does!

You would need to perform a recursive directory walk (e.g. in Python), call **avprobe** (via a subprocess), parse the duration from the output and store play length and filename in a suitable structure.